# People picker shows duplicate entry for FBA users

Tags: people-picker

While making entry in people picker control for FBA user it shows me duplicate entry.Though there is only one entry.Please let me know what is the reason behind it.

[image: Duplicate entry for FBA user for same domain]

Comment: Can you check the domain of both the user's?

Comment: There is only one user name "FBATESTUSER". Still it is showing "fbatestuser". I have created only single user.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue.

Maybe there are multiple types of authentications enabled for the SharePoint zone, for example Claims and Active Directory.