# FBA Extranet - Inconsistent Access Denied for different users

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, groups

Update: the issue appears to be related to our OU structure. The accounts that aren't working are in a different OU. But we're not sure what in the OU structure would prevent their logging-in. They're all in the same sub-tree so should be found.

Microsoft so far hasn't been able to assist us - they stated to check the password on the account(s), but we can confirm they are correct.

---

Update: sorry, the behaviour is inconsistent. Some users can login, others can't (either via group membership or directly assigned to site).

It makes me wonder if it's related to the PortalSuperReader/PortalSuperUser accounts and the Publishing feature, but doesn't explain that some users can continue to login OK.

---

Our users can login to our Extranet FBA site if they've been directly assigned to the site, but not if they're assigned permissions via a SharePoint Group. The permission assigned is exactly the same. What could cause this?

The standard FBA login error is: "The server could not sign you in. Make sure your user name and password are correct, and then try again."

There is nothing in the IIS or ULS logs that I can see. (You're only logged in IIS if you have Full Control via the Web Applicaiton `User Policy` and can login OR if you have no permissions and get redirected to the "Sorry this page hasn't been shared with you" page).

Answer (score 1):

Does your FBA web application have multiple types of authentications and you set permissions to the account of another authentication ?

[People picker shows duplicate entry for FBA users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128719/people-picker-shows-duplicate-entry-for-fba-users)

http://curia.me/post/2014/09/11/sharepoint-2013-duplicate-entries-in-people-picker-with-adfs-authentication.aspx

Comment: Thanks - we're certainly assigning the correct FBA "membership" permission as that shows-up as the login name, while the Windows version shows-up as their full name.